# Why does my time x-axis turn into numbers instead of years? Heatmap/2D histogram of multiple data points

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have ~550 latlon coordinates with daily sea surface temperature data. I want a visualization like a heatmap/2D (or even 3D?) histogram to show the spread of all the data points. Below you'll see what I've been able to come up with. It's daily data from 1/1/1982 to 12/31/2020, so 365days*38 years. Each day there are ~550 points plotted, and as you can see by the colorbar most points lie closest around 0, but some go much higher or lower. 
**My issue with this is the x-axis**: I want it to show years, I don't know why it is displaying those weird numbers.

[image: Text]

Here's the code that achieved it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5))
im = ax.hist2d(master_df['time'], master_df['SSTA'], bins=(456, 100), norm=colors.LogNorm(), cmap='turbo')
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Temperature anomaly (\xb0C)', fontsize=12)
plt.title('2D histogram of all SSTAs by day-of-year', fontsize=18, pad=20)
plt.ylim([np.min(master_df['SSTA']), np.max(master_df['SSTA'])])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im[3], ax=ax)
cbar.set_label('# data points')
plt.show()
```

Here's the dataframe my code references:

```
    time        lat     lon  dayofyear ssta   month 90th        10th  threshold year
0   1982-01-01  24.125  262.375 1   -1.331715   1   1.566037    -1.658169   0   1982
1   1982-01-02  24.125  262.375 2   -0.774280   1   1.566037    -1.658169   0   1982
2   1982-01-03  24.125  262.375 3   -0.342742   1   1.566037    -1.658169   0   1982
3   1982-01-04  24.125  262.375 4   -0.380434   1   1.566037    -1.658169   0   1982
4   1982-01-05  24.125  262.375 5   -0.240177   1   1.566037    -1.658169   0   1982
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
7649560 2020-12-27  30.375  273.875 362 0.104458    12  1.385149    -1.384631   0   2020
7649561 2020-12-28  30.375  273.875 363 -0.060157   12  1.385149    -1.384631   0   2020
7649562 2020-12-29  30.375  273.875 364 -0.051952   12  1.385149    -1.384631   0   2020
7649563 2020-12-30  30.375  273.875 365 0.083945    12  1.385149    -1.384631   0   2020
7649564 2020-12-31  30.375  273.875 366 -0.310837   12  1.385149    -1.384631   0   2020
7649565 rows × 10 columns
```

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm.  Rusty.  If no one else comments... maybe you need something like `plt.plot(master_df['SSTA'])` above the line `plt.show()`??  Something like that.  Oh, and at the top on import probably set the index as your time like `master_df = master_df.set_index('time')`

Comment: A simple way to set the date format automatically is to use the following method.　`import matplotlib.dates as mdates;im = ax.hist2d(mdates.date2num(master_df['time']), ...);locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator();formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator);ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator);ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. Thank you @r-beginners

```
ax.hist2d(mdates.date2num(master_df['time']), ...)
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```